# Remove options which values are not included in array using purely JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

I need to remove options from  a drop-down list that are not included in an array. This is what I tried:

```
var states_served = ["Connecticut", "Delaware", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New York", "North Carolina", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "Vermont", "Virginia", "West Virginia"];

var statesDD = document.querySelector('select[title="State"]');

 for (i = 0; i < statesDD.options.length; i++) {
  console.log(states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value)); //Correctly finds false and true options
     if (states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value) === false) {
       statesDD.remove(i);
       }

     }
```

If I try the opposite `if (states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value))`, just for testing, t removes the one that are `true`, but I need to remove the ones that are `false`. I also tried:

```
if (states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value) == false)...
if (states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value) !== true)...
if (!states_served.includes(statesDD.options[i].value))...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your current problem is that when you are removing the array elements based on their initial position `i`, you are not accounting for the fact that you are removing them from the array. Thus, `i` will not be a correct iterator relative to the final array.

One way to avoid this is to use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to avoid having to manage the indices yourself:

```
var statesDD = document.querySelector('select[title="State"]')
  .filter((state) => !(states_served.includes(state.options[i].value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `states_served` into a `Set` to make it so the equivalent operation of `includes` on a Set, `has`, is `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` before using `filter`:

```
const states_served = new Set(["Connecticut", "Delaware", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New York", "North Carolina", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "Vermont", "Virginia", "West Virginia"]); 

let statesDD = document.querySelector('select[title="State"]')
                       .filter(state => states_served.has(state.options[i].value));
```

This will filter all the values which are false and only keep the true ones which I think you asked in the question if you want the reverse just add a `!`.